# jeditable not working with enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, jeditable

My jeditable doesn't update to the new value when a user hit the enter key to save.

When I click on the field, change the value and hit the OK button everything works as expected. When I click on the field, change the value and hit the ENTER button the database value is updated, the response is the new value but the value in my HTML changes back to the old value.

This is my JS:

```
$('.answer-info-block .answer').editable('/question/saveAnswer', {
       type: 'text',
       submit: 'OK',
       cancel: 'Cancel',
       style: 'display: inline'
});
```

For testing purposes the only thing saveAnswer does for now is:

```
echo $_POST['value'];
```

Comment: So, just to clarify, the php portion IS being triggered, but the html element isn't changing the text to show the new version? Or is none of it triggering at all?

Comment: Yes, it is triggered but the html element isn't changing. Just tested it again and in Firefox it works as expected, but in Chrome and IE it doesn't change the html. When I reload the page it shows the new value because the database does get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, it may help:
[$.Ajax request is not working in Chrome](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-request-is-not-working-in-chrome)